book lungs on a human?
I want my character (a human spider hybrid) to have book lungs along with human lungs, would there be any glaring disadvantages to this, would they be fragile be sensitive to smells? .

(a) SE requires that you ask one question at a time. You're asking two. (b) There is no space within human physiology for additional organs. You're having to push something aside to make a little room, which has consequences. In other words, they're always a disadvantage. They're redundant and less efficient for a creature the size of a human. Does that make them a bad worldbuilding idea? No, only that science will never be your friend here. Embrace the fantasy that you're seeking to create. Organs are placed for efficiency, protection, etc. Where would you put them?

As @JBH said, it would be a waste of precious body volume. Warm-blooded animals need a lot of oxygen in order to sustain their high metabolic rate, and for this purpose their lungs must pack as large as gas exchange surface into the limited volume available. Human lungs pack a gas exchange surface of about 80 square meters into a volume of about 6 liters. Moreover, the (admittedly very thin) chitin layer of the respiratory surfaces of arachnid lungs is much less permeable by oxygen than the (equally thin) alveolar epithelium of vertebrate lungs.

What's the relationship between lungs and smells? The sense of smell has nothing to do with the lungs. (Except that for us land-dwelling animals smells are carried by air, so that the smell receptor organs are placed along the conduit which carries the air to the lungs. Fish have a good sense of smell, but for them the smell is carried by water, they have no lungs at all, and the smell receptors are completely separate from the path of water to their gills.)

you could use mammalian lungs plus book lungs to create a more air sac like arrangement, which is more efficient, but not by much.

The only issue is space
If you're keeping the human lungs there isn't much of a reason why adding a pair of book lungs would cause any real issues, besides them taking up space in the body
This issue can be solved with another aspect of arachnid anatomy, that being the digestive tubules: It is plausible enough that the small intestine could function well enough if it is distributed as a straight central tube and a set of tubules branching off, as is seen in spiders. This arrangement would have a higher surface-area-to-volume ratio, justifying a smaller total lumen volume, as well as allowing said volume to be more freely distributed around the abdominal cavity: This should allow space for a pair of small book lungs

huh, I like that idea do you think that would seriously affect diet?

@spiderwriter By the time human food gets to the small intestine it is pretty much fully broken down, so I doubt that changing the shape of the intestine would really affect a human diet
